# Get distinct records where column is highest

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table of columns of which I would like to get the highest dollar amount for each distinct (month) column. Is there a simple way to capture the records in SQL Server?

### Original Table

```
ID  ProjID  Month   Spent
1   14  Oct  $11,846.00 
1   6   Oct  $82,000.00 
2   8   Nov  $6,051,645.00 
2   9   Nov  $408,744.00 
3   7   Dec  $165,827.00 
3   6   Dec  $485,160.00 
4   1   Jan  $10,300.00 
4   7   Jan  $249,656.00
```

### Desired Results

```
ID  ProjID  Month   Spent

1   6   Oct  $82,000.00 
2   8   Nov  $6,051,645.00 
3   6   Dec  $485,160.00 
4   7   Jan  $249,656.00
```

The following query I tried displays all records.

```
SELECT
    [MAX_T].[ID],
    [MAX_T].[ProjID],
    [MAX_T].[Month],
    [MAX_T].[MaxSpent]
FROM
    @Table1 [T] INNER JOIN
    (SELECT [ID], [ProjID], [Month], MAX([Spent]) AS [MaxSpent]
    FROM @Table1
    GROUP BY [ID], [ProjID], [Month]) AS [MAX_T]
    ON [T].[ProjID] = [MAX_T].[ProjID] AND
       [T].[Month] = [MAX_T].[Month] AND
       [T].[Spent] = [MAX_T].[MaxSpent]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Spent DESC)
    FROM dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT  ID,
        ProjID,
        [Month],
        Spent
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to have the query select the first 4 records for example?

Comment: @Ropeh What do you mean?, this query should work for SQL Server 2005+

Comment: This should be correct, but I think you want to `PARTITION BY` month, not ID.

Comment: @laylarenee yes, you are right, it's just that the sample data showed one value of ID per month too

Comment: @Ropeh what does "first 4" mean?

Comment: @Ropeh Well, that's awkward, you changed your first comment so my reply seems like it came from nowhere

Comment: Hi Lamak. My sincere apologies for the late response. Your code worked flawlessly and I tried to let you know after my first response.

Comment: @Aaron, using the Top(n) function in SQL.

Comment: @Ropeh TOP (n) ORDER BY <what>?

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to consider the data in sets:

1st get a set with the highest dollar per month then join that set back to the base set to get the addtional data...

```
SELECT A.* 
FROM @TABLE A
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT Month, Max(Spent) as MSpent
  FROM @Table1
  GROUP BY Month) B
on B.Month = A.Month, B.MSpent = A.Spent
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution xQbert. Got it to work using Lamaks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it:

```
select ID, ProjID, Month, Spent, RowNo 
from (
    select ID, ProjID, Month, Spent,
        ROW_NUMBER ()
        over (
            PARTITION BY Month
            order by Spent DESC
            ) as RowNo 

    from (
        select ID, ProjID, Month, Spent
        from Table1
    )
    where RowNo = 1
)
```

This is untested code - I just substituted your field names for mine.